# How to find edges between nodes more efficiently?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, network-analysis

I have an undirected Graph G=(V,E) and its adjacency matrix `x` in DataFrame format and a list of nodes `NODE` subset of V. I want to find out all the edges b/w the nodes of `NODE`.

I have tried the following code. Is there any other efficient way of doing it in terms of time complexity? Please help me.

```
    import networkx as nx
    import random

    G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100000,0.4)
    x =nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G)
    NODE=[]
    [NODE.append(random.randint(1,99999)) for i in range(1000)]
    edges=[]
    [edges.append((NODE[i],NODE[j])) for i in range(len(NODE)-1) for j in range(i+1,len(NODE)) if(x.loc[NODE[i],NODE[j]]==1)]


    print(edges)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as a list, then a reasonably efficient (and simple to interpret) code is:

```
edges = list(G.subgraph(NODE).edges())
```

Comment: what is the time complexity of the subgraph() method? Is it better in terms time complexity? @Joel

Comment: Not sure of the inner workings (but a lot better than what you were doing)